# How can I manipulate an image using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image

I have stored an image in a scrambled type of form on the server, which I then display to the user. I would like to use Javascript to dynamically descramble the image on the client side.

Are there ways to do this? I think I need some way to manipulate the image as a binary object to descramble it.

Answer (score 3):

You could base64 scramble and descramble it with JavaScript and then get the resulting base64 and insert it into an `img` tag in your html:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" 
   src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

However your scrambling algorithm is still available to the user - as much as you hide it or minify it, an expert JS programmer can understand what's happening no matter what.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to scramble the algorithm itself, I'm trying to scramble the image server side, then descramble it client side using a password provided by client, without hitting the network.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a canvas.

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
```

load an image and draw it in the canvas :

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    can.width = img.width;
    can.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
}
img.src = 'toto.jpg';
```

and then, you can use methods of the context to manipulate the image :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the pixel data into canvas and manipulate it there.  There's a solid answer available here: [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)